# Paste the names of a columns in which there is a "Y" in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, tidyverse

In my `DATA` below, I want to create a `New_Column` which pastes the names of columns `A:F` in which there is a `Y` to achieve my `Desired_Output`.

I was wondering if this might be possible in R?

```
DATA <- read.table(h=TRUE,t="
ID  A   B   C   D   E   F
1   Y   Y   N   N   N   N
2   N   N   N   Y   N   N
3   Y   N   Y   N   Y   N
4   Y   Y   N   N   N   N
5   N   N   N   Y   N   N
6   Y   Y   Y   N   N   N
7   N   N   N   N   N   N
8   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA")

Desired_Output <- read.table(h=TRUE,t="
ID  A   B   C   D   E   F   New_Column
1   Y   Y   N   N   N   N   A_B
2   N   N   N   Y   N   N   D
3   Y   N   Y   N   Y   N   A_C_E
4   Y   Y   N   N   N   N   A_B
5   N   N   N   Y   N   N   D
6   Y   Y   Y   N   N   N   A_B_C
7   N   N   N   N   N   N   N
8   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of steps with the **tidyverse**:

```
library(tidyverse)

new_col <- DATA |> 
  pivot_longer(-ID) |>
  filter(value == 'Y') |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  summarize(new_column = paste(name, collapse = '_'))

new_df <- left_join(DATA, new_col, by = 'ID')

  ID    A    B    C    D    E    F new_column
1  1    Y    Y    N    N    N    N        A_B
2  2    N    N    N    Y    N    N          D
3  3    Y    N    Y    N    Y    N      A_C_E
4  4    Y    Y    N    N    N    N        A_B
5  5    N    N    N    Y    N    N          D
6  6    Y    Y    Y    N    N    N      A_B_C
7  7    N    N    N    N    N    N       <NA>
8  8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>       <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, You could do this in an `apply` statement across rows (`1`):

```
DATA$newcol <- apply(DATA, 1, \(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x[-1])), 
                                          NA, 
                                          paste(names(x)[grepl("Y", x)], collapse = "_")))
```

Output

```
#   ID    A    B    C    D    E    F newcol
# 1  1    Y    Y    N    N    N    N    A_B
# 2  2    N    N    N    Y    N    N      D
# 3  3    Y    N    Y    N    Y    N  A_C_E
# 4  4    Y    Y    N    N    N    N    A_B
# 5  5    N    N    N    Y    N    N      D
# 6  6    Y    Y    Y    N    N    N  A_B_C
# 7  7    N    N    N    N    N    N       
# 8  8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>   <NA>
```